# password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, configuration, users

The `sample.sql` is simple.

```
create database test;
```

The settings on `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf`.

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Execute `sample.sql` in command console:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres sample.sql
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Same error for(restart postgresql service after changing the configuration file):

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

Answer (score 2):

if you speify a host it makes a TCP/IP connection to that host.
"local" requires unix domain sockets

to make a local (unix domain socket) connection don't specify a host.

```
psql -U postgres < sample.sql
```

Alternatively you could say 127.0.0.1/8 or ::1/64  instead of local if you must for some other reason use a TCP/IP connection

Comment: psql -U postgres < sample.sql